# I am flying tonight and wonder if I can use wireshark even without paying for inflight wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I am flying tonight and am learning about networks. I was wondering if I use wireshark or other packet capturing program, will I see traffic if I am connected to the network but do not pay for it?

I am new to networking and want to use the time on the flight to learn and explore.

Comment: Try it and see? This is not an InfoSec question.

Comment: I definitely will regardless of people answering. Just want to know if I have to bring something else to occupy my time. Sorry for posting in InfoSec.

Comment: what network will you connect to if you dont pay?

Comment: You can connect to gogo but get redirected back to their site if you don't pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not addressing any potential legal issues, airline security related stuff, contractual agreements, or terms of service issues but from a strictly technical stand-point yes.

Almost all of the airlines allow the use of their own apps or connections to a given airlines home page without paying for the service. In order for that to work they allow people to connect to the 802.11 network prior to payment/agreement of terms. Therefore yes you will see some traffic including the access point's mac address/IP address and some of the traffic on-board. There is nothing really unusual here in that it's just a normal 802.11 network using your regular built-in 802.11 wireless device drivers and you will see 802.11 traffic as you would anywhere else.

This said I think you'd learn more from downloading a lot of sample PCAP's of varying protocols from WireShark Sample Captures page:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will I be able to see other peoples traffic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes (from a purely technical standpoint as well), not paying for internet only determines whether you can access networks beyond the captive portal and does not affect your ability to see traffic on the network. You may need to use monitor mode (or non-passively, arpspoofing) to see traffic other than multicast, broadcast, and unicast traffic to/from to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can, you could even (if you're willing and have the correct technology) clone someone else's MAC address and kick them off the in-flight network with something such as aircrack-ng and steal the wifi they paid for. Then you will have no need to sniff out their credentials or personal information and just sit back, relax, and watch a movie while someone else unknowingly pays for your indulgences.

In saying that, being connected to the inflight network as stated above does not necessarily mean you are directed to the network. Generally you are sent to a http server which will authenticate the information you were given when you 'paid' to use their service. Otherwise you are only allowed within the LAN.

Comment: If you can out your wireless card in promiscuous mode, you we'll be able to monitor all Wi-Fi traffic within range. As stated above, you can use Wireshark offline looking at pcaps previously captured out downloaded. The Wireshark wiki had excellent resources.